# Use "arp -a" to retreive MAC address of corresponding IP Adress

Tags: c#, string, list, ip-address, mac-address

I was trying to convert the MAC address of my phone to it's IP address.

```
var arpStream = ExecuteCommandLine("arp", "-a");
List<string> result = new List<string>();
   while (!arpStream.EndOfStream)
  {
      var line = arpStream.ReadLine().Trim();
      result.Add(line);
  }
```

Using the above code, I store it in a list in the following form:

```
  192.168.137.1         2e-bb-58-0a-2f-34     dynamic
  192.168.137.44        a8-3e-0e-61-3f-db     dynamic
  192.168.137.91        d4-63-c6-b2-ac-38     dynamic
  224.0.0.22            01-00-5e-00-00-16     static
  224.0.0.252           01-00-5e-00-00-fc     static
```

What I can't figure out is, how to retrieve a specific IP for the given MAC.
Assume that my phone is the device with the physical address: a8-3e-0e-61-3f-db, how can I store it's IP as a string somewhere?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
String s = "";
for (int i = 3; i < result.Count(); i++)
{
                s = Convert.ToString(result[i]);
                if (s.Contains(macAddress))
                {
                    break;
                }
}
char[] ip = new char[15];
StringBuilder ipaddr = new StringBuilder();
for (int i = 0; s[i].CompareTo(' ') != 0; i++)
{
                ipaddr.Append(s[i]);
}
return ipaddr;
```

I used each entry in the result list as a string and looked for my MAC as a substring inside all of the entries.

Answer (score 0):

I'm assuming you've got the list of strings somehow (`ExecuteCommandLine` method) and want to be able to filter it based on arp value. Regex can be an option then:

```cs
void Main()
{
    // just setting it up for testing
    List<string> result = new List<string>();
    result.Add("192.168.137.1         2e-bb-58-0a-2f-34     dynamic");
    result.Add("192.168.137.44        a8-3e-0e-61-3f-db     dynamic");
    result.Add("224.0.0.22            01-00-5e-00-00-16     static");
    result.Add("224.0.0.22            01-00-5e-00-00-16     static");
    result.Add("192.168.137.91        d4-63-c6-b2-ac-38     dynamic");
    result.Add("224.0.0.22            01-00-5e-00-00-16     static");
    result.Add("224.0.0.252           01-00-5e-00-00-fc     static");

    // this is the part you want
    ConcurrentDictionary<string,string> arps = new ConcurrentDictionary<string, string>();
    foreach (var s in result)
    {
        var matches = Regex.Match(s, @"((?:\d+\.?){4})\s+((?:[0-9a-f]{2}-?){6}).*");        
        arps.TryAdd(matches.Groups[2].Value, matches.Groups[1].Value);
    }

    Console.WriteLine(arps["01-00-5e-00-00-16"]);
}
```

**note:** opting for dictionary here has benefits as well as drawbacks.
you will get [`O(1)`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37348446/why-is-accessing-an-element-of-a-dictionary-by-key-o1-even-though-the-hash-fun) element access times, but you can't have duplicate MAC addresses there. Without knowing your specific use case it's a bit hard to say whether this tradeoff will apply to you, I'm just pointing this out as an option.

Answer (score 0):

You can use a **`Dictionary`**  *data structure* in C# to hold `key-value` pair information in your case it is `Ipaddress-Macaddress` information

[image]

**Usage**

```
var macofIpaddress = dict["192.168.137.1"];
```

**Code**

```
string output = "";
var proc = new ProcessStartInfo("cmd.exe", "/c arp -a")
{
      CreateNoWindow = true,
      UseShellExecute = false,
      RedirectStandardOutput = true,
      RedirectStandardError = true,
      WorkingDirectory = @"C:\Windows\System32\"
};
Process p = Process.Start(proc);
p.OutputDataReceived += (sender, args1) => { output += args1.Data + Environment.NewLine; };
p.BeginOutputReadLine();
p.WaitForExit();


var dict = new Dictionary<string, string>();
var lines = output.Split(new string[] { "\r\n" }, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries);

foreach(var line in lines)
{
      if (line.Contains("static") || line.Contains("dynamic"))
      {
         var elements = line.Split(new string[] { "    " }, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries);
        var ipAdd =   elements[0].Trim();
        var macAdd = elements[1].Trim();
        dict.Add(ipAdd,macAdd);
      }



}
```

**Output**:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You can create a model class that will store the IP information like :

```
public class DeviceIPAddress
{
    public string IPv4 { get; set; }

    public string MAC { get; set; }

    public string IPType { get; set; }
}
```

Now, we can use this model to parse the provided list, in which will make it easier for us to handle :

```
var ips = new List<DeviceIPAddress>();

foreach (var ip in result)
{
    var info = ip.Split(new char[] { ' ' }, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries);
    ips.Add(new DeviceIPAddress { IPv4 = info[0].Trim(), MAC = info[1].Trim(), IPType = info[2].Trim() });
}
```

now using the `ips` list, we can manage the received data easily :

```
var getIP = ips.First(x => x.MAC.Equals("a8-3e-0e-61-3f-db", StringComparison.InvariantCultureIgnoreCase));
// call getIP.IPv4 will to get the IP 192.168.137.44
```